# Application InstallException on emulator in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I tried a simple program on fragment of android but am not able to get the output.Please suggest solutions.Following errors are listed in console

```
[2014-01-21 14:12:29 - Fragmt1] Failed to install Fragmt1.apk on device 'emulator-5554!
[2014-01-21 14:12:29 - Fragmt1] (null)
[2014-01-21 14:12:29 - Fragmt1] Failed to install Fragmt1.apk on device 'emulator-5554': EOF
[2014-01-21 14:12:29 - Fragmt1] com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: EOF
[2014-01-21 14:12:29 - Fragmt1] Launch canceled!
```

Comment: Do you realy have to put the whole question in title?

Comment: That was a mistake,sorry.I expected answer.

Comment: Thank you.But its not working.